# Jasmine Node testing child processes

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, tdd, jasmine

Just wrote a module that grabs the current IOStat of a production box to determine if it is being over worked.

Interesting problem - there isn't really a way to testing a callback function with Jasmine; well, at least one that I have found.

Spies were the first thing that came to my mind, but since it actually calls the function directly, that isn't possible. Of course, I could always define this function as a var and do a spy.

```
proc.exec('iostat -c | tail -n2', function(err, out, s){

    if(err) throw err;

    misc();

}
```

The only reason why I would want to test this - is because I'm developing on a windows machine that doesn't have all of these commands available, so I would like to intercept it and throw in the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to spy on `proc.exec` and get the callback function out of the `spy.mostRecentCall.args` array and call at then by your self:

```
spyOn(proc, 'exec')
//run your code
proc.exec.mostRecentCall.args[1](true)
```

As this isn't very convenient you can use [sinon](http://sinonjs.org), where you can create a  stub that call the callback automatically with `stub.callsArgWith(index, args)`.

```
sinon.stub(proc, 'exec').callsArgWith(1, true);
//run your code
```

Comment: Worked well, great idea. I honestly can't believe I didn't think of that - seems so simple. Thank you.